# How to SetWindowPos and SetWindowPlacement with physical coordinates

Tags: winapi, multiple-monitors, highdpi

My app is multi-DPI aware, and when we call `SetWindowPos` or `SetWindowPlacement`, we do so with a rectangle calculated for the appropriate monitor. However, it seems that these functions assume the provided size is for the *current* DPI, and scales it. Worse, during `WM_CREATE`, it does not use `WM_GETDPISCALEDSIZE` to scale the size, but simply scales linearly, so we cannot correct the size.

Is there a way to force `SetWindowPos` or `SetWindowPlacement` to use exactly the provided window size (in unscaled coordinates)?

Comment: There's more than one flavor of DPI aware.  Which are you using?

Comment: I'm using DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2